# why service worker download new content automatically, but doesn't update?

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, vue-cli

I register service worker this way:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log('App is being served from cache by a service worker.');
    },
    registered() {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.');
    },
    cached() {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.');
    },
    updatefound() {
      console.log('New content is downloading.');
    },
    updated() {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
    },
    offline() {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    }
  });
}
```

when I `vue-cli-service build --mode production` and then I deploy to the server, online I can correctly see the logs:

```
App is being served from cache by a service worker.
Service worker has been registered.
New content is downloading.
New content is available; please refresh.
```

It seems to download automatically the content, but from now, it still always show `New content is available; please refresh` (and in fact, the content is not refreshed).
It seems it won't refresh automatically? Only downloading? Why?

How can I refresh on `updated()`?

Comment: did you tried closing the tab and opening again?

Comment: i don't want this. it should reload "reloading" the page. why close/open...

Comment: I am curious did you try to `location.reload`?

Comment: @Estradiaz what do you mean? I think it will reload automatically as for download the content. Should I write somethings more?

Comment: This lib just wraps some events to state changes. I am not sure if you want "random" reloads per default when it is just one line of code to add it, but some weird event handling to prevent it.

Comment: @Estradiaz but it doesn't make sense that it "download" but not reload. Does it?

Comment: There many pages that use a Snackbar to inform about new version to not interrupt usage. Consider bad connection and after 10min the page reloads and in the worst case puts you back to start.. but with a short message the user can just refresh

Answer (score 0):

what I did in this situation was to resolve a promise that will reload the page for the user. This is nice because it waits and then does the page reload after the data has come in.

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log('App is being served from cache by a service worker.');
    },
    registered() {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.');
    },
    cached() {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.');
    },
    updatefound() {
      console.log('New content is downloading.');
    },
    updated() {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
      Promise.resolve().then(() => { window.location.reload(true); });
    },
    offline() {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `skipWaiting` method of service worker object.

maybe this can help you:

```
updated(registration){
    const waitingServiceWorker = registration.waiting;

    if (waitingServiceWorker) {
      waitingServiceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', event => {
        if (event.target.state === 'activated') {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      });
      waitingServiceWorker.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
    }
}
```

whether this code is working or not depends on your `service-worker.js` content.

but the idea is the same you should use `skip waiting`.